# Inducing sparsity in a Bayesian model

Tags: bayesian, modeling, sparse

Can someone explain or point me to an introductory reference that deals with the notion of sparsity in Bayesian modeling? What does the idea of sparsity really mean? What does it mean to 'induce sparsity'? How are 'sparse priors' identified and used? In fact, what are they?

Comment: Maybe you can start with an old paper: Sparse Bayesian Learning and the Relevance Vector Machine http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume1/tipping01a/tipping01a.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a Bayesian linear regression:
$$Y_i = x\beta_i + \epsilon_i$$
$$\beta_i \sim N(\beta_0,\Sigma_0)$$

One version of sparsity is to use a Laplace distribution (aka double exponential) as a prior for the $\beta$ coefficient in a Bayesian linear regression, as opposed to the Normal distribution one often uses. Here is a visual:

[image]

The double exponential places much more weight around zero which "pulls" in small $\beta_i$ values and makes them 0, while leaving large values of $\beta_i$ still nonzero. This effectively zeros out many values in your parameter matrix, and hence induces sparsity. This is similar to the frequentist lasso.

Comment: The Cauchy Distribution as defined in Wikipedia looks different. How do you define the Cauchy Distribution in the example above?

Comment: (+1) Think that should read "a Laplace distribution (aka double exponential)"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be truly Bayesian (sample from a posterior that gives you sparse parameterizations), the only way I know of is a spike-and-slab type prior. A Laplace prior gives sparsity only in the MAP estimate.